# PyMongo: Removing a nested object without knowing the key

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('abc'), 
  'customer': 'bob',
  'products': {
  '1234': 
    {'name': 'Shirt', 
    'productID': 5
    },
   '5679': {
    'name': 'Hat', 
    'productID': 5
    }
   }
   '1011': {
    'name': 'Jeans', 
    'productID': 9
    }
   }
}
```

I am looking to remove all nested objects whose 'productID' property is 5, so the collection would look like this afterwards:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('abc'), 
  'name': 'bob',
  'products': {
   '1011': {
    'name': 'Jeans', 
    'productID': 9
    }
   }
}
```

I know the following information:

```
customer: bob
productID: 5
```

Is it possible to do a  wildcard on 'products'? Something like this (it does not work):

```
db.update({'customer':'bob'}, {'$unset': {'products.*': {'productID': 9}})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice, refactor your data to make each item a list element, e.g.

```
{
    'customer': 'bob',
    'products': [
        {'code': '1234',
         'name': 'Shirt',
         'productID': 5
         },
        {'code': '5679',
         'name': 'Hat',
         'productID': 5
         },
        {'code': '1011',
         'name': 'Jeans',
         'productID': 9
         }
    ]
}
```

Then your update becomes a piece of cake:

```
db.mycollection.update_one({'customer': 'bob'}, {'$pull': {'products': {'productID': 5}}})
```

result:

```
{
    "customer": "bob",
    "products": [
        {
            "code": "1011",
            "name": "Jeans",
            "productID": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

Persisting with poor choices of schema will no yield long term rewards.